# Is it possible to create a 1Inch limit order, when tokens are stored in a smart contract?

Tags: dapps, 1inch-dex-aggregator, escrow

I am trying to find a way to create a 1inch order, where I wouldn't be holding the tokens, but would only be approved.

Currently, 1inch requires the signature of the token holder when placing an order, but since I'm storing the tokens in an escrow contract, I can not create a signature, nor does 1inch support EIP-1271.

Is there any other way to achieve this, that I'm missing?